# Using phpLDAPadmin and configuring slapd

Tags: ldap, openldap

So, I've run through this guide here:

https://help.ubuntu.com/11.04/serverguide/C/openldap-server.html

to the point where I have pushed the backend and frontend directory. So now I have an admin account and password, as well as some OUs.

Well I would like to use phpmyadmin to add more users and stuff but after I log in I get this message on the left:

dc=nodomain
This base entry does not exist.Create it?

Clicking "Create it?" doesnt do anything and I cannot interact with my existing directory tree.

I found a guide from 2009 on how to set it up slapd and use phpLDAPadmin but it's either outdated or my existing setup is conflicting with it. What can I do? Can I completely purge my system of any and all LDAP stuff?

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned and unanswered, could you perhaps add more detail to your question? If this question no longer applies then you can either delete it or answer it yourself if you've solved the problem. Thanks!